# Why Video grid is moving chat grid in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

Hey guys iam implementing a video call based application in html.I had done with all the circumstances so far but the major problem is whenwever the new member joins in the call the window move along with the chat what I need is chat should be stiff and should not get moved the video window should scroll left.

Moreover How can I fit the videos as grid as 3*3 or 4*4 or 8*8 type here.

```css
#video-grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5 px;
}

video {
  height: 300 px;
  width: 400 px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.main__chat_window {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.main__videos {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10 px;
}

.main__left {
  flex: 0.8;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main__right {
  flex: 0.2
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main__left">
    <div class="main__videos">
      <div id="video-grid">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main__controls">
      <div class="main__controls__block">
        <div onclick="muteUnmute()" class="main__controls__button main__mute_button">
          <i class="fas fa-microphone"></i>
          <span>Mute</span>
        </div>
        <div onclick="playStop()" class="main__controls__button main__video_button">
          <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
          <span>Stop Video</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main__controls__block">
        <div onclick="security()" class="main__controls__button main__security">
          <i class="fas fa-shield-alt"></i>
          <span>Security</span>
        </div>
        <div onclick="share()" class="main__controls__button main__share">
          <i class="fas fa-share"></i>
          <span>Share</span>
        </div>
        <div class="main__controls__button">
          <i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i>
          <span>Chat</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div onclick="leaveMeeting()" class="main__controls__block main__leave_meeting">
        <div class="main__controls__button">
          <span class="leave_meeting">Leave Meeting</span>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main__right">
    <div class="main__header">
      <h6>Chat</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="main__chat_window">
      <ul class="messages">

      </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="main__message_container">
      <input id="chat_message" type="text" placeholder="Type message here...">
    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Put some dots in your question and paste your html.

Comment: do you want the chat to right side and video screens to the left side?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here if that's you want:

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
}
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.main{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}
#video-grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5 px;
}

video {
  height: 300 px;
  width: 400 px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.main__chat_window {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.main__videos {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10 px;
}

.main__left {
  flex: 0.8;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
.main__chat_window{
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.main__right {
  flex: 0.2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main__left">
    <div class="main__videos">
      <div id="video-grid">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main__controls">
      <div class="main__controls__block">
        <div onclick="muteUnmute()" class="main__controls__button main__mute_button">
          <i class="fas fa-microphone"></i>
          <span>Mute</span>
        </div>
        <div onclick="playStop()" class="main__controls__button main__video_button">
          <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
          <span>Stop Video</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main__controls__block">
        <div onclick="security()" class="main__controls__button main__security">
          <i class="fas fa-shield-alt"></i>
          <span>Security</span>
        </div>
        <div onclick="share()" class="main__controls__button main__share">
          <i class="fas fa-share"></i>
          <span>Share</span>
        </div>
        <div class="main__controls__button">
          <i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i>
          <span>Chat</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div onclick="leaveMeeting()" class="main__controls__block main__leave_meeting">
        <div class="main__controls__button">
          <span class="leave_meeting">Leave Meeting</span>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main__right">
    <div class="main__header">
      <h6>Chat</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="main__chat_window">
      <ul class="messages">

      </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="main__message_container">
      <input id="chat_message" type="text" placeholder="Type message here...">
    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```